# Dynamically Created Menu Item with attached code?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I'm reading 2 values from an INI File: The Section Name, & The value of the key named "Path"

[Game Name]

Path=C:\Game\Game.exe

What i'm trying to do is create a Context Menu Item with the caption being the Section "Game Name" and have it launch the application from the value of the "Path" key. I haven't worked much with dynamically created controls in the past, so i'm wondering if there's an easy way to create it, and assign a single line of code to it to launch the application.

Is it possible, or is there an easier way of going about it?

foreach (string SecHead in SectionHeader)
                    {
                        string[] Entry = myINI.GetEntryNames(SecHead);

```
                    if (Entry != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string EntName in Entry)
                        {
                            ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
                            row.Add(SecHead);
                            row.Add(myINI.GetEntryValue(SecHead, EntName));
                            DGV.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());

                            string filePath = Convert.ToString(myINI.GetEntryValue(SecHead, EntName));

                            //Create ContextMenu Entry from Data Above
                            Icon newIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you know how to read the INI values and that they are in `String` variables.  Let's also assume you are doing this in an event handler that supplies mouse coordinates, such as a `MouseUp` event:

```
var section = "section";
var gameExe = "c:\\somepath\\mygame.exe";
var menu = new ContextMenu();
var item = new MenuItem(section);
item.Click += (s, args) => { Process.Start(gameExe); };
menu.Items.Add(item);
menu.Show(this, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

Not tested live, but this should give you the general idea.